# Ruby, SQLite and trigonometric functions

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I want to be able to use various trigonometric to find the distance between latitudes and longitudes from ruby using the SQLite database. SQLite doesn't provide trigonometric functions (`cos`, `sin`, `pow`) so I'm looking for how to implement these functions - any ideas?

I know I can use other databases (PostgreSQL, MySQL etc) but I need to use SQLite so no database installation is required. Any ideas as to how to compile extensions for SQLite that I can insert into the sqlite3 gem?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this at the database level, rather than in Ruby? Why?

Comment: @Henning Doing it in C at the sqlite level is a couple magnitudes faster if you have a large data set or need to call this function a lot (e.g. real time location search with large datasets, running trip planning algorithms, data analysis etc) Though often in those situations you'd implement the entire thing in C/C++ and just wrap it in ruby. What I normally do is approximate the distance to reduce the sample size in sql and then run the distance calculations in ruby. That assumes you've reduced the sample size small enough. Any more than 500 points and the speed difference becomes noticeable.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, but it looked like the OP was looking to do this as SQL expressions, rather than either C or Ruby. If the OP was planning to use C/C++ for the spherical distances, then I don't understand what the question is. C certainly does have trig functions.

Comment: @Henning, The OP also asked about compiling extensions for sqlite, so I assumed that means custom sqlite functions http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_create_function and then wrapping it up into a ruby extension, which is quite a lot of work.

Comment: My understanding of the problem that faces me may not be complete - I have a statement I can execute in MySQL using `sin`, `cos`, `atan2`, `pow` etc (the inverse haversine formula) and I'd like to use it to list all of the rows of my SQLite database in ascending order of distance from a point. There's unlikely to be more than a few thousand rows in this table, but I'd like to optimise for speed.

Comment: If I can do this in Ruby without a big performance hit then I'm game!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If writing an extension is too much work, what I normally do for this problem is to approximate the distance i want to select (and over estimate a bit) by using a lat/lng bounding box which reduces the sample space significantly, and then iterate over that set in ruby to find the exact set of points within the right distance.

Edit: Looks like someone has already written a library that lets you easily define functions as if they were stored procedures. I don't know if it's a ruby implementation or if it does some trickery to compile it down to C first, so I don't know the performance, but it seems pretty easy to use. https://github.com/copiousfreetime/amalgalite

```
require 'rubygems'
$: << "../lib"
$: << "../ext"
require 'amalgalite'
db = Amalgalite::Database.new( "mydb.sqlite" )
db.define_function( 'geo_dist' ) do |lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2|
  # Haversine formular here to calculate the distance
end
```

Here's the full example
https://github.com/copiousfreetime/amalgalite/blob/master/examples/define_function.rb

Comment: This looks like it might be just the ticket - will investigate!

Comment: This library is absolutely perfect - but it doesn't work with the latest version of Active Record! (The Active Record adapter is also tied to an earlier version of Amalgalite too). I'll try and get it working, but my knowledge of the ActiveRecord internals isn't really up to scratch.